# android: safe way of starting activity from a view

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I've built a simple customized view and registered onClickListener() in a constructor. To start a new Activity when view instance is clicked, I simply used something like this:

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), com.test.myClass.class);
            Context context = getContext();
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Since my knowledge level is still very poor, I was wandering if this is a good way to start activity from View and what would be a better way if there is one?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in this case, but otherwise your code should work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this implementation is very valid, but could be improved with two little things:

```
YourView extends View{

  private boolean clicked = false;

  private final View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener = 
  new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!clicked){
            clicked = true;
            Context context = getContext();
            Intent i = new Intent(context, com.test.myClass.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            context.startActivity(i);   
        }
    }
  }


  public View(Context ctx){
    super(ctx);
    setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
  }
}
```

the improvement is the following: If the user clicks like crazy on your View, it can be the case that the `OnClickListener` is trigered more than once, and therefore starts multible Activitys. The boolean fixes it. 
Also your `OnClickListener` is always the same, though you can just declare it once inside your View and don't instantiate them more than once.

Note: You might need to set `clicked` back to false at some point (`onPause()` of the Activity which holds your View seems to be a reasonable place)